# Not able to access session storage while page routing in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, session, axios

When I am routing my page on sign up submit, then I am submitting the email in sessionStorage.

**But while getting the item from session storage I am not able to do so. My page is routing to another page after submission of sign up**.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "../axios/axios.js";

export class SignUpRedirect extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      U_Id: null,
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await axios.get("/Organization");
    const idData = response.data;
    idData.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.Email === sessionStorage.getItem("email")) {
        this.setState({ U_Id: item.U_Id, isLoading: false });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState = (state, callback) => {
      return;
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="donestatus-container">
        You Have Signed Up And Your Organization Id is :{" "}
        {this.state.isLoading ? "...loading" : this.state.U_Id}
        <div className="donestatus-container-inner">
          <Link to="/sign-in">
            <h4>Sign In</h4>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpRedirect;
```

**I am not able to find suitable answer. Can anyone help me out?**

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, as you need to parse sessionStorage object, which is like a JSON Onject:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await axios.get("/Organization");
  const idData = response.data;
  idData.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.Email === JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("email"))) {
      this.setState({ U_Id: item.U_Id, isLoading: false });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Still not getting it. Actually My program is running correctly but when I submit my sign up detail and page routes then it only shows loading.... , not giving me the result, but when I refresh the page it starts showing me the data...it means that it is not able to get the value in sessionStorage but after refresh it does . Can you please explain me where I am doing wrong.